# Keeping MYSQL connection open

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to keep MySQL connection **open** from the beginning of a php file and **close** it at the end of that particular script? 
If yes please help me because I'm having problem with this:
[Prevent clash in MYSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48774958/9356725)

Thank you all.

Comment: Probably you can fix that using table locking

Comment: Multiple people are likely to use the table at the same time. Table locking won't be a good idea.

Comment: That's precisely your problem, you're expecting updates / selects work well from two different scripts, so a locking problem...

Comment: Okay bro! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I open and close connection with my database:

```
$host = "localhost";
$root = "myusername";
$pass = "mypassword";
$DBname = "mydatabase";
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $root, $pass, $DBname);

function close_connection($link) {
  $link ->close();
}
```

I call the function `close_connection()` whenever I want to stop the connection with my database. Hope this helps!

-Ed

Comment: I really appreciate what you mean. But if you check this
https://stackoverflow.com/q/48774958/9356725
something is going wrong somewhere.

Comment: Wrapped my head around that problem for a while, can't really think of anything, sorry and good luck!

Comment: Thanks bro. I really appreciate your time.